# Get rid of dead floating explorer context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

At some point I've right clicked in Explorer to open a file in Notepad++ and the context menu is left floating around on my screen.

- I've killed off both Explorer and Notepadd++ but the context menu remains.
- I've tried to drop the window identification target from Process Explorer on to it but Process Explorer doesn't seem to see it.

Its really annoying because I don't want to reboot at the moment and its hovering right over everything! Does anyone know how to kill these things off without a reboot?

Thanks!

[image: floating context menus]

Comment: Is this only with this exact message? Is it only with notepad++? Does it happen even if you don't click that option?

Comment: It only happens very rarely but now that I think about it, it does seem to be Notepad++ specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimise all apps, then try the following:

- Change your screen resolution and then change it back.
- Run a full-screen app and then close it.
- Use your monitor's auto-adjust option if it has one.

Comment: Nice thinking, changing the screen resolution fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up Task manager, then find dwm.exe in the processes and kill the process. In a second, the explorer interface comes back and the dead item is gone.

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to work 3/4 times. Then dwm stops appearing

Answer (score 0):

Floating CMs are annoying as hell and happen even in Xfce (GTK) here on my Debian desktop.  However, the first technique I usually try used to work in Windows as well.

What I do is that I basically close them by Esc.  However, that won't work if something else has the focus already, so now the tricky part is to get the focus on the menu without clicking an item in it:

1. Click a disabled item or a separator

   This is obviously not possible when there's no such item, or even when there's *only
   one item* as we can see on your screenshot.
2. Click *and hold* left ("the main") mouse button over the item, drag the mouse pointer
   off the item and release the button.
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>